# get timeZone syntax for US pacific time

Tags: java

I have seen code where they mention UTC, i just wonder what is the syntax for US pacific time.

```
Calendar cal_Two = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

is it like below.

```
Calendar cal_Two = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("USP"));
```

Comment: java and javascript ain't the same thing.

Comment: Avoid the three-letter time zone names, they are legacy things that are ill-specified. Use the Olson instead (such as `America/Los_Angeles`). Also: "US pacific time" is not a time zone, even if many think it is. It's a rule set used by *various timezones at various times*.

Comment: ZoneId https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html

Comment: Also avoid using the obsolete `Date` and `Calendar` classes. They're not designed very well. Instead, use the newer Java Date and Time API, available in the `java.time` package.

Answer (score 1):

### Prefer ZonedDateTime and ZoneId over Calendar and TimeZone

Allow me the opportunity to recommend java.time, the modern Java date and time API. I am aware that your code lines are taken out of a larger context that I don’t know, so switching to java.time may be entail a bit more work than that. It will most probably be worth it.

- If you are writing new code, use java.time throughout and forget about `Calendar` and the other old classes.
- If you are writing code that needs to interoperate with legacy code using `Calendar`, still consider using java.time in your own code. Straightforward conversions exist for when you need to pass a `Calendar` to a legacy method.

`Calendar` and `TimeZone` are poorly designed and long outdated. The modern API is so much nicer to work with and generally lends itself to more concise and more natural code that it will be much easier to maintain.

### Likely America/Los_Angeles will fulfil your purpose

I believe that the America/Los_Angeles time zone covers the part of the USA that uses Pacific Time (Pacific Standard Time in the winter and Pacific Daylight Time in the summer): California, Nevada, Washington and greater parts of Oregon and Idaho.

Always give time zones in the *region/city* format like America/Los_Angeles or Europe/Kiev. Other formats have been used previously and are still seen, but they are no longer encouraged. Particularly a lot of two, three, four and five letter abbreviations should be avoided since they are often not true time zones and often ambiguous. Even for UTC the recommended official ID is Etc/UTC (even though Etc hardly counts as a region of the Earth).

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(zone);
    System.out.println(zdt);
```

Output when  I ran this code just now:

> 2020-04-23T09:35:22.842667-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]

`ZonedDateTime` is the most natural and general replacement for the old `Calendar` class, but exactly which java.time class to choose depends on your more precise requirements. Please go through the classes or a tutorial and pick the one that is right for you. One of the many advantages of `ZonedDateTime` over `Calendar` is that you get readable output when you print it.

To convert to a `Calendar` that you can pass to your legacy API:

```
    Calendar calTwo = GregorianCalendar.from(zdt);
```

### Tutorial link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.